# A new type of Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

[image]

I have very little idea about how to approach this question. It doesn't make any sense to me how this can be Cauchy. Any insight into it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You just deleted the question, why?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose that $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is Daudhy, and let $\epsilon>0$. There is a $T\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(a_j,a_k)<\frac{\epsilon}2$ whenever $T<j<2T<k$. Use the triangle inequality to show that $d(a_j,a_k)<\epsilon$ whenever $j,k>2T$ and conclude that the sequence is Cauchy.